# How to convert .mat file to NIFTI file with Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

I have a `.mat` file, called `m1.mat`, the size of which is `40*40*20 double`.
The values in the `m1.mat` file is either `0` or `1`. I want to convert this `.mat` file to `NIFTI` format by using Matlab? How to do it?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before using a tag.

Comment: Try here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image

Comment: @rayryeng, can you write an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package from MathWorks FEX seems to be what you're looking for: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image .  This package was written by Jimmy Shen from the Rotman Research Institute at Baycrest, which is affiliated with the University of Toronto in Canada.

However, to be self-contained, I'll provide you with some sample code to get started using this package.

Assuming your 3D matrix is stored in a variable called `im`, you would first need to build a NIfTI structure from the 3D matrix, and then you'd save the NIfTI structure.

Something like this:

```
nii_img = make_nii(im);
save_nii(nii_img, 'm1.nii');
```

Comment: @Shawn - no problem. Good luck!